# Ace editor lines overlaps each other

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, ace-editor

I have a strange behavior of Ace editor on websites. Editor lines overlap each other.

https://ace.c9.io/
[image]

https://editor.swagger.io/
[image]

Here the same problem in Postman:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6760

Environment:

- Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138
- MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem here https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/4300

It was a problem with font Monaco on my computer. I had two copies of this font, one was broken. I deleted it using Font Book for MacOS. Now the editor looks good.

[image]